# How can I resize an image already uploaded using Magickwand(PHP)/ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am working on building gallery where the user uploads all the images.  I had tried to use GD originally but found that it used way too much memory when dealing with images from a digital camera.  So I have been looking into ImageMagick and ran into this problem.

My end goal is to resize the image and then upload it.  I am not sure if this is possible with ImageMagick or not.  I have gotten it to resize the image after upload but it doesn't save the resized image, just the original size.

This is the code I am currently using: ($image is the path to the file on my server)

```
$resource = NewMagickWand(); 
MagickReadImage($resource,$image); 
MagickSetImageCompressionQuality( $resource, 100);
$resource = MagickTransformImage($resource,'0x0','660x500');
```

Any input would be appreciated,

Levi

Comment: can you please explain more about what the problem is? is it in writing the resized image, or in dealing with the uploaded image?

Comment: Well I guess I am a bit confused about how ImageMagick works.  I can print out the resized picture, but it doesn't change on my web server.    I am wondering if there is a command for making the changes permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will send the modified image to the client (the web browser), but it will not save it to the server (replacing the original image, for example)

To save the image, use:

```
MagickWriteImage( $resource, 'new_image.jpg' );
```